# Jenking plugin installation fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed the Jenkins app in mac server.
when I try to install the plugin I'm getting below failure message.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1317)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:128)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:115)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.getShortName(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:101)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:418)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1313)
```

What would be reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the plugin download has failed. The plugins are actually zip files. You could try if you can unzip the plugin yourself. If it is damaged, you could remove it and try to install it again.

Comment: I'm manually downloading the *.hpi files from updates.jenkins-ci.org and uploaded from Jenkins interface.  Jenkins -> Plugin Manager -> Advanced -> Upload plugin